# BER vs SNR plot in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting

I have a bit-error-rate (BER) function and I am interested in plotting it against the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). I need to use a plot function that is similar to the LogPlot but I need the Log function to have a base of 10 instead of e.
I even tried the following, but it yields incorrect results:

```
Plot[Log[10,BerFunction],{SNR,0,30}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider using `ParametricPlot[]` instead of `LogPlot[]`, then.

Comment: Standard BER-SNR plots appear fine with `LogPlot`. Make sure your `BerFunction` output is correct when the input `SNR` value is in dB.

Comment: Please add code /data to enable reproduction of your problem.